# Contour integral over a positively oriented circles $|z|=2$ and $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Contour integral over a positively oriented circles $|z|=2$ and $|z|=1$
>
> where $$f(z)=\frac{1}{cosz}$$

Does Cauchy-Goursat theorem work for both circles?

Or do I have to substitute in $$cos(z)=\frac{e^{-iz}+e^{iz}}{2}$$ and integrate from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ for both circles?

Comment: Where is $f$ holomorphic (differentiable)? Also, do you know the residue theorem? You can work with Cauchy's integral formula but residue theory makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$ is an even function so the integral in both cases is zero: replacing $z$ by $-z$ still traverses the circle in the same direction but multiplies the integral by $-1$.

Comment: Does this mean that any integral of an even function over a circle will equal to 0?

Comment: Yes. another way to see this is that the residue of an even function at any point $z$ cancels with the residue at $-z$.